# finding the index of the first row matching a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I understand I can do something like this:

```
df[df['data'] > 3].index.tolist()
```

and take the first element of the list

but the place I need to use it is in a loop with a lot of iterations and a very large dataframe.
I want to get the first instance and stop the execution right there instead of wasting time to collect all instances to then discard all results but the first one.

Is there a way to do this with Pandas? manually iterating through the rows is crazy slow; splitting the dataframe into chunks and doing a search in each doesn't help that much (possibly because it does some copies, not sure).

edit:
here's an example

```
data = {'data': [10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18]}   # this is over 1M entries in practice
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.index[df['data']>14].tolist()[0]
```

this returns 4, as expected.

what I want is to find a fast way to stop execution the moment there is one row matching the condition.

Comment: I added an example, although it doesn't really make a difference in the question since it's related to the API.

Comment: since it is an API, i assume that it comes in JSON? why not treat it as a dictionary and find your number. Should be much faster than loading into a dataframe

Answer (score 4):

#### `idxmax`

Still evaluates a boolean series prior to evaluating `idxmax`

```
df['data'].gt(3).idxmax()
```

---

#### `argmax`

```
df.index[(df['data'].to_numpy() > 3).argmax()]
```

---

#### explicit function

```
def find(s):
    for i, v in s.iteritems():
        if v > 3:
            return i

find(df['data'])
```

---

#### Numba

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def find(a, b, c):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if y > c:
            return x

find(df.index.to_numpy(), df['data'].to_numpy(), 3)
```

Comment: unfortunately it's the two cases from the question: scanning everything, or slowly iterating through the elements, which happens to be much slower (looks like this is generally very slow in Python). I cut the dataframe in chunks to be able to skip if I find a result; it is faster than these two methods, but still very slow.

Comment: The problem I found with "argmax" and "idxmax" solutions is that if the condition is not met by any line, you are going to get the first line as answer...even if it does not meet the condition.